# 10 Gb network card connection

Tags: networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet, network-interface

I have just bought the intel X540T2 shown below and when I opened my machine I am not sure if I can plug it in any of the available PCIe slots shown below? If anyone could please advise

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you expect to gain from fitting a high speed 10 Gbit nic to this host ?  It appears to be a desktop.

Comment: @Criggie I'm considering fitting a 10 Gbit nic to my desktop, why would that be strange? Getting tired of the embarassing 100MB/s or so from my NFS server!

Comment: @pipe depends if the server can create and sustain 10 Gbit of traffic, and the client can receive and use it.  There's not really that much need, specially when OP's data sink is an older desktop (implied by the PCI slots)  I'm curious about OP's use-case mostly.   Pipe: you'd have to upsize your NFS server NIC, switch, maybe cabling, and have enough fast disks to push 1000 Mbytes/sec for sustained periods to make it worth doing.

Comment: If you are really determined to make it work, you can try one of those "Vertical GPU Bracket " to relocate the x4 under the GPU elsewhere or relocate the GPU elsewhere...

Comment: @user3528438 what do you mean by Vertical GPU Bracket?

Comment: Cable and mounting hardware that allows GPU to be mounted parallel to the motherboard. Google it.

Comment: @user3528438 May be if there is an extension pcie x4 cable so I can connect the 10Gb card to it and place it horizontal in it’s normal position downward? And can I use a pcie x16 extension cable or it has to be x4?

Comment: If your x4 slot is open ended like your x1 then yes you can use a x16 cable. But since the slot is under your GPU cooler, you should pay attention to the clearance issues.

Comment: I'm guessing by the way that this motherboard has plain pci slots you should try for 1000mb/s before 10gb/s. I can't quote a theoretical max bitrate, but i will say I've been supprised how often the hardware driver is included (on Linux) and hardware can work outside of what might be an expected configuration (ex, pcie slot mismatches).  I've run all my desktops with ten gb nics, and would certainly recommend it for how cheap they are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically yes, but you will *not* be able to reach 10 Gbps speed with them. The only slot that's fast enough is already occupied by your GPU.

You have these slots, from top to bottom:

0. I'm guessing a PCI-Express x16 slot – can't see it through the GPU, but most motherboards *usually* put an x16 slot there. It would accept your network card if you removed the GPU.
1. A PCI-Express x4 slot that's also occupied by the GPU, if squircle's findings are correct. It could accept your network card, probably.
2. A PCI-Express x1 slot (blue) with a cutout to accept any-size PCIe card. It will accept your network card, but will only provide 1 data lane. If your motherboard provides PCIe version 2.0, then 1 lane will *only* be enough for 5 Gbps (probably slightly below that).

   (Actually, I don't know whether your card will *work at all* in a x1 slot – as far as I know, generally they're supposed to, but it's possible that it might deliberately refuse to.)
3. Another PCI-Express x1 slot (blue). Same as #2 above.
4. A *Conventional PCI* slot (white). It is *not* a PCI-Express slot and does not accept any PCIe cards. (And even if it did, Conventional PCI only barely provides enough speed for 1 Gbps, let alone 10 Gbps, so don't go looking for adapters.)
5. Another Conventional PCI slot (white). Same as #4 above – not PCIe.
6. Third Conventional PCI slot (white). Same as #4 above.

Comment: It is an x16, and there's an x4 behind the GPU too ([motherboard page](https://www.aaeon.com/en/p/atx-imba-q77/)).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the GPU was a fat one. But it doesn't look like the same model actually? The one you found has black slots with no cut-out for larger cards, unless it's a different revision.

Comment: Are there any 10Gbit PCIe cards designed for PCIex1 slot?

Comment: @user1686 Might be a different revision. If you zoom in to the 2nd picture just above the x1 NIC, it says "IMBA-Q77 Rev:" before being cut off by the GPU.

Comment: @squircle yes, there is a PCIe x4 slot covered by the GPU. Will this work with this card? Is this GPU too fat or most GPU will cover this PCIe x4 slot?

Comment: And how to know if my motherboard provides PCIe version 2.0?

Comment: If it's not in the manual, then maybe check using CPU-Z or GPU-Z? As for x1 slots, you can get ~10 Gbps from one lane if your motherboard _and_ your network card both support PCIe version 3.0 (note that's 10 Gbps raw PCI speed, it probably still won't give you 10 Gbps network speed), but not if either of them uses an older version.

Comment: @Tak Your motherboard uses the [Intel Q77](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64027/intel-q77-express-chipset.html) chipset which has PCIe 2.0. A PCIe x1 slot with PCIe 2.0 will not handle the traffic from a 10Gbit card.

Comment: And the card will work in a PCIe x1 slot according to the [datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/ethernet-x540-datasheet.pdf) of the on-board Intel X540 controller.

Comment: @pipe so this card will work in the PCIex1? What will be the max traffic allowed?

Comment: @Tak It should work according to all the documentation, but it can only do _absolute max_ 4 Gbit/s, on one port at a time, likely a little bit less than that.

Comment: @pipe thanks, this sounds good to me actually. And if the two ports are used then how much transfer you think?